# yodoctor: command not found when installing yo from terminal

Tags: npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yo

Below is the error I keep getting. It seems to indicate a "post-install" issue with yodoctor. Sadly yodoctor is the advice given by the yeoman team to help with this issue. I have other node_modules installed (bower, grunt, typescript).

```
sh: yodoctor: command not found
npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.0.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.9
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! yo@1.5.0 postinstall: `yodoctor`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the yo@1.5.0 postinstall script 'yodoctor'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the yo package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     yodoctor
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls yo
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/jesselawson/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you install node/npm will brew or by which method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is generally caused because someone used `sudo` at some point and messed up their npm package directory permissions. As a rule of thumb, never ever use sudo.

So how can you fix it? Here's a couple troubleshooting points:

1. Make sure you update npm to the latest version (`npm install -g npm`). npm 2.x had some race conditions that would try to run `yodoctor` before it is installed.
2. Make sure the global npm module folders is [`chown`/`chmod` to your user](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm).
3. Make sure [npm module binaries is in your PATH](http://notions.me/post/adding-npm-bin-to-path).
4. If nothing works, then you can force install it by running `npm i -g yeoman-doctor && npm i -g yo` - but that really is a last recourse solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just the following command would do the trick:

```
sudo npm install -g yo
```

if not, find where `yo` is, add it to the path as follows:

```
export PATH="$PATH:<path where yo is installed>"
```

Comment: I wanted to reinforce that I think Simon Boudrias' answer is more my situation, and seems like a more appropriate solution.  This happened after receiving multiple sudo-required situations, and finally changing my npm prefix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25447784/1091943.  Similar to what baksosapi said, an npm update, and -h yo install again worked.
https://github.com/yeoman/yo/issues/465#issuecomment-237986250