# npm install -g less does not work: EACCES: permission denied

Tags: node.js, npm, terminal

I'm trying to set up less on phpstorm so I can compile .less files to .css on save. I have installed node.js and the next step (according to this https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html) is running this command in the terminal

```
npm install -g less
```

However when I do this I get these errors

```
☁  ~  npm install -g less
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/brentscholl/.npm/mkdirp/0.5.1'
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/brentscholl/.npm/graceful-fs/3.0.8'
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/brentscholl/.npm/extend/3.0.0'
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/brentscholl/.npm/readable-stream/2.0.4'
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/brentscholl/.npm/chalk/1.1.1'
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/brentscholl/.npm/xtend/4.0.1'
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
/usr/local/lib
└─┬ less@2.5.3
  ├─┬ errno@0.1.4
  │ └── prr@0.0.0
  ├── image-size@0.3.5
  ├── mime@1.3.4
  ├─┬ promise@6.1.0
  │ └── asap@1.0.0
  └─┬ source-map@0.4.4
    └── amdefine@1.0.0

npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "less"
npm ERR! node v5.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.6
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/brentscholl/npm-debug.log
```

I'm a complete noob here and not sure what to do next. Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 504, accepted):

Using sudo is not recommended. It may give you permission issue later.
While the above works, I am not a fan of changing folders owned by root to be writable for users, although it may only be an issue with multiple users.
To work around that, you could use a group, with 'npm users' but that is also more administrative overhead.
See here for the options to deal with permissions from the documentation:
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

I would go for option 2:

> To minimize the chance of permissions errors, you can configure npm to
>   use a different directory. In this example, it will be a hidden
>   directory on your home folder.
>
> Make a directory for global installations:
>
> ```
>  mkdir ~/.npm-global
> ```
>
> Configure npm to use the new directory path:
>
> ```
>  npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
> ```
>
> Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:
>
> ```
>  export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
> ```
>
> Back on the command line, update your system variables:
>
> ```
>  source ~/.profile
> ```
>
> Test: Download a package globally without using sudo.
>
> ```
> npm install -g jshint
> ```
>
> If still show permission error run (mac os):
>
> ```
> sudo chown -R $USER ~/.npm-global
> ```

This works with the default ubuntu install of:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

I recommend `nvm` if you want more flexibility in managing versions:
https://github.com/creationix/nvm

On MacOS use brew, it should work without `sudo` out of the box if you're on a recent `npm` version. 
Enjoy :)

Comment: Heads up-- on Ubuntu 18.04 I had to log out and log back in before the change was applied automatically too all new terminal windows.

Comment: Alexander, did you make sure you used the source command? That should take care of setting the right environment variables, logging out shouldn't be needed (but works).

Comment: this didnot work

$ npm install -g jshint
npm ERR! write after end

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/xx/.npm/_logs/2019-02-22T06_35_08_821Z-debug.log

Comment: this works even for `npm i -g yarn`... the `sudo chown...` method doesn't work for that

Comment: if anyone is struggling with that solution on macos 11 - I had to use export PATH="${HOME}/.npm-global/bin/:$PATH" instead; my system didn't want to understand what "~" is in PATH
EDIT: or just use homebrew as author suggests :)

Comment: Btw: `nvm` moans about using a prefix as described above (means trouble for this otherwise excellent solution): `Your user’s .npmrc file (${HOME}/.npmrc) has a 'globalconfig' and/or a 'prefix' setting, which are incompatible with nvm.`

Answer (score 132):

Run these commands in a terminal window (note: DON'T replace the $USER part... thats a linux command to get your user!):

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/lib/node_modules
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to make yourself the owner of things in `/usr`? What if someone else wants to install node stuff?

Comment: Worked for me on macOS High Sierra, I only needed one of the three commands:
`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules`. @Mark That's true, but it's of course no problem if you only have one user.

Comment: @FabianvonEllerts Well, it's still easier to accidentally delete system files, since you won't need sudo anymore... I'd just follow best practices even when alone, but it's up to you of course.

Comment: I'm with Mark, unless you have one user (and even then) you don't want to have the /usr sub directories owned by one user, in that case, better use the group. But perhaps even better, just use brew as I mentioned in my answer, it will work without root out of the box.

Comment: this method doesn't work for `npm i -g yarn`

Comment: Do not use this, its too dangerous. It messed up the permissions and had to re-install the ubuntu again in my VM.

Answer (score 34):

**Mac OS X Answer**

You don't have write access to the node_modules directory

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Add your User to the directory with write access

1. Open folder containing node_modules

   open /usr/local/lib/
2. Do a cmd+I on the node_modules folder to open the permission dialog
3. Add your user to have read and write access in the sharing and permissions section
   [image]

Comment: to open that directory in terminal write `open /usr/local/lib/`

Comment: This will only change permissions for node_modules folder, not all the folders inside, which makes these steps pretty much useless.

Answer (score 15):

[image]Use sudo -i to switch to $root, then execute npm install -g xxxx

Answer (score 12):

Reinstall node and npm with **Node Version Manger** (as per [written in npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)) to avoid permission errors:

In OSX:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash
```

or follow this article:

http://dev.topheman.com/install-nvm-with-homebrew-to-use-multiple-versions-of-node-and-iojs-easily/

*Windows users should install [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows).
For further help how to install nvm refer the [nvm readme](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md#installation).*

Then choose for example:

```
nvm install 8.0.0
nvm use 8.0
```

Now you can give another try:

```
npm install -g less
```

Answer (score 11):

For my mac environment

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

solve the issue

Comment: I believe this is already covered in @VagnerRodrigues's answer above.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this command with the root password to add permission for writing for `node_module` folder:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all the suggested solutions but nothing worked.

I am using macOS Catalina 10.15.3

Go to /usr/local/

Select bin folder > Get Info

Add your user to Sharing & Permissions.
Read & Write Permissions.
[image]

And go to terminal and run npm install -g @ionic/cli

It has helped me.

Comment: to open that directory in terminal write `open /usr/local/lib/`

Answer (score 1):

sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
This command will work

Answer (score 1):

You can try with sudo, like the following

```
sudo npm install -g less
```

If it does not work, you can refer to this link
https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/tips#resolving-permission-errors

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same problem.
updating npm was not working for me either so I just decided to reinstall it.

what worked for me is uninstall node from my system using.

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs    
sudo apt-get remove npm
```

end then reinstall it after update.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install npm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing with `sudo`. I had a similar problem installing npm package globally. The problem occurs because current use does not have write permissions for making changes in directory.

Didn't work

```
npm i -g vsce
```

Worked

```
sudo npm i -g vsce
```

Answer (score -2):

In linux make sure getting all authority with:

```
sudo su
```

Answer (score -3):

Another option is to download and install a new version using an installer.

https://nodejs.org/en/download/