# error when npm install

Tags: angularjs, npm

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to learn Angular so I'm trying to install a new project with angular-seed. But when I do npm install I get an error that I dont know where is coming from. I have node installed. The version is 5.5.0. Ad this is the error I get in console.

```
npm verb install Error: Unsupported
npm verb install     at checkPlatform (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-install-checks/index.js:46:14)
npm verb install     at Array. (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/bind-actor.js:15:8)
npm verb install     at LOOP (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:15:14)
npm verb install     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:18:7
npm verb install     at checkEngine (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-install-checks/index.js:25:10)
npm verb install     at Array. (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/bind-actor.js:15:8)
npm verb install     at LOOP (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:15:14)
npm verb install     at chain (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/lib/chain.js:20:5)
npm verb install     at module.exports.isInstallable (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/validate-args.js:26:3)
npm verb install     at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/deps.js:452:12)
npm verb lock using /home/david/.npm/_locks/staging-7c9a6a9e85daffeb.lock for /home/david/DiabetesApp/angular-seed/node_modules/.staging
npm verb unlock done using /home/david/.npm/_locks/staging-7c9a6a9e85daffeb.lock for /home/david/DiabetesApp/angular-seed/node_modules/.staging
npm verb stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/david/DiabetesApp/angular-seed/node_modules/.staging'
npm verb stack     at Error (native)
npm verb cwd /home/david/DiabetesApp/angular-seed
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-76-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--verbose"
npm ERR! node v5.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! path /home/david/DiabetesApp/angular-seed/node_modules/.staging
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/david/DiabetesApp/angular-seed/node_modules/.staging'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/david/DiabetesApp/angular-seed/node_modules/.staging']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/home/david/DiabetesApp/angular-seed/node_modules/.staging' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm verb exit [ -13, true ]

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/david/DiabetesApp/angular-seed/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: use sudo npm install

Answer (score 2):

**ISSUE**: You (the user) don't have the right set of permissions for the directory.

The instant way out is to run the npm install using sudo, but this may give you the same error, or improper installation.

---

**Solution**/**Suggestion**: Change npm's Default Directory (from official [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-two-change-npms-default-directory))

Back-up your computer before moving forward.

(optional) In case you have a erroneous installation, first uninstall it:

```
npm uninstall <package-name>  # use sudo if you used it while installation
npm cache verify  # or, npm cache clean for npm version below 5.x.x
```

1. Make a directory for global installations:

   **`mkdir ~/.npm-global`**
2. Configure npm to use the new directory path:

   **`npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`**
3. Open or create a `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` file and add this line:

   **`export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`**
4. Back on the command line, update your system variables, or restart the terminal:

   **`source ~/.profile`**
5. (optional) Test: Download a package globally without using sudo.

   **`npm install -g jshint`**

Answer (score 0):

"Please try running this command again as root/Administrator."

Try `sudo npm install`.

Comment: I've already tried this. But I get this in console Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported WARN lifecycle angular-seed@0.0.0~postinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) angular-seed@0.0.0 bower install /home/david/DiabetesApp/angular-seed

Comment: I've found this [issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9204) on github. You could try to use another version of npm.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission problem. You must fix permissions on this directory, and run `npm install` without sudo.

```
cd your_working_directory
sudo chown -R $( whoami ):$( whoami ) .
sudo chmod -R 755 .
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid EACCESS errors do reinstall node and npm with **Node Version Manger** (as per [written in npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)).

For furtner details visit this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49126536/5506730