# How to install create-react-app through terminal

Tags: node.js, create-react-app

I am installing create-react-app through terminal. I have checked the node.js version is 4.5.0, which is higher than the requirement [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html). and the version of npm is 2.15.9. Then I type the command `npm install -g create-react-app` , there came out such error information:

```
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/xiufenxu/.npm/create-react-app/0.6.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 16.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "create-react-app"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack:
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:35:25',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:47:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)' ] }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/xiufenxu/Documents/UM courses/Fall 2016/CSCI 5117/npm-debug.log
```

Why did I get such errors and how do I prevent them from occuring?

Comment: See the links here:
Suggested three ways of fixing it. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725639/npm-install-g-less-does-not-work)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
sudo npm install -g create-react-app
```

you're running it as a user without root permissions

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you! Did you know this from the line `npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app'`?

Comment: see suggested answers here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725639/npm-install-g-less-does-not-work

Comment: If the above answer didn't work, please uninstall it first `sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and then the above answer will work

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my computer fixed it for me