# Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/build'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am trying to run an Angular application. I execute the [`ng serve`](https://angular.io/cli/serve) command, but it then shows:

> Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'

Comment: Use npm version 5.2.0. For more details go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147896/error-in-cannot-find-module-node-sass/52982654#52982654

Comment: Follow this :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147896/error-in-cannot-find-module-node-sass/52982654#52982654

Answer (score 155, accepted):

**Solution:**

You need to change the ownership of folder [`node_modules`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder), because you use `sudo npm install -g node-sass`, so its ownership is set to root.

To change the ownership to the current user as group -

```
sudo chown -R root:$(whoami) /usr/local/lib/node_modules/

sudo chmod -R 775 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```

And never use `sudo` for an `npm`-related query.

Comment: worked for me but by not putting root: ahead of username in first command

Comment: Instead of the first command use this ```sudo chown -R root:YOUR_USERNAME /usr/local/lib/node_modules/```

Comment: after that i got one more error: ```checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules``` but this answer was helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/40905762/9277453

Comment: on mac OS : sudo chown -R $(whoami):staff /usr/local/lib/node_modules/

Comment: although it should work, it's a bad idea to change permissions there. Please refer to this answer so that is not needed : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725639/npm-install-g-less-does-not-work-eacces-permission-denied/40905762#40905762

Comment: Thanks @benek.. Your response worked for me in MacOS

Comment: `sudo chown -R <your-username>: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/` also works

Answer (score 64):

Run this command

```
sudo npm install -g <ModuleName> --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Comment: This worked for me. Any explanation would be helpful.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What are the security implications of it? How does it work? Why does it work? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57777965/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 32):

I was working in [Ionic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_(mobile_app_framework)) and had this issue, so I solved this by moving one folder back and running this command:

`sudo chmod  -R 777 project-directory`

And after this:

`npm install node-sass --save`

Answer (score 25):

Try this

> sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-sass

Or this

> sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm --verbose @angular/cli

Comment: I have a machine using root user to run npm install and still failed. Only `--unsafe-perm` does work.

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me -

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: On a brand new M1 mac this was the only answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

This is due to the user's permission. The user from which you are running the command of `npm install` is probably doesn't have permission. So you are getting errors.

For that user just give the permission for that project folder.
In **[Mac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh)**, use the below steps and give read and write permission to the user for that project folder

- On your Mac, select a disk, folder, or file, and then choose menu *File* → *Get Info*.
- If the information in *Sharing & Permissions* isn’t visible, click the arrow.
- If the lock at the bottom right is locked, click it to unlock the *Get Info* options, and then enter an administrator name and password.
- Click a user or group in the *Name* column, and then choose a privilege setting from the pop-up menu.

  - Read & Write: Allows a user to open the item and change it.
  - Read-only: This allows a user to open the item but not change its
    contents.
  - Write only (Drop Box): Makes a folder into a drop box. Users can
    copy items to the drop box, but can’t open it. Only the owner of
    the dropbox can open it.
  - No Access: Blocks all access to the item.

This helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of answers we want, not *"Try this"* or *"This worked for me"* answers without an explanation and with unspecified security implications.

Answer (score 6):

Run these commands on your terminal:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin/
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/share/
```

Answer (score 2):

**2023 Working Solution**

```
npm i --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

if node_modules is owned by root, then do

```
sudo su //switched to root user
npm i --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

Reference: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2824#issuecomment-575960022

Answer (score 1):

Try this: **npm install node-sass@version**

If you want the latest, then just try **npm install node-sass**.

If you're getting an access problem then:

1. Windows: command prompt in administrator mode, and then run the above.
2. Mac:

   ```
    sudo npm install node-sass
   ```

#### References

- *[ERROR in Cannot find module 'node-sass'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147896/error-in-cannot-find-module-node-sass)*
- *[Windows: 'npm install node-sass' fails when module 'install.js' cannot be found. #603](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/603)*

Answer (score 0):

If you have not added Node.js *pakage.json* yet, try running `node init`. If you already have this, `npm install node-sass`.

If both are present and you are using [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), try changing the permission of the folder using `chmod -R <path to node module>`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not in the *home* directory or other places. You need to go back to root.

Use this command

```
cd ..
cd ~
```

Your current location should look like:

```
~$
```

After this, run the command to create a project.

Comment: Why would `cd ..` make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

u need to use a "root" user in your shell,

with this command:

sudo su -

then you should enter your password

and then try to install the package, i think it will work with any package that you try to install globally

more info that help me in this website

http://www.dark-hamster.com/programming/how-to-solve-error-message-eacces-permission-denied-in-nodejs-application/

Comment: As stated in some of the other answers, running `npm` commands as `root` should be avoided whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

right click on node_modules folder
select get info
give the access permission (read and write)