# npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, npm, monaca

## **Note:** Due to security concerns, please don't use the marked solution but instead [the highest voted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54170648/131120)!

---

original question:

I am trying to install monaca with this command.

```
npm install -g monaca
```

But right after getting these errors:

> ```
> npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules 
> npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
> npm ERR! code EACCES
> npm ERR! errno -13
> npm ERR! syscall access
> npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
> npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
> npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
> npm ERR!   errno: -13, npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
> npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
> npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
> ```

Any idea how to solve this problem?
Thank you

Comment: See [what the **npm** docs have to say about this](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally).

Answer (score -19, accepted):

An inadvisable way to fix the issue would be to use sudo:

```
sudo npm install -g monaca
```

However it would be better to find a way around this without using sudo.

[npm install -g less does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725639/npm-install-g-less-does-not-work/40905762#40905762)

Comment: please give a full fledged permission based final fix not just sudo things

Comment: don't use `sudo` with `npm`, [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40905762/6282576)

Comment: You literally just said it was inadvisable - so don't be part of the problem and give that advice.

Comment: this will ofcourse work for once but npm will not work as it should be

Answer (score 106):

add following lines to ~/.bashrc after installing npm:

```
npm set prefix ~/.npm
PATH="$HOME/.npm/bin:$PATH"
PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
```

Execute following line after changes:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

and as mentioned by @contemplator avoid using `sudo`

Comment: **NOTE: Do not use `sudo`**
If using [Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) add the lines above to `~/.zshrc` after installing npm.
Execute following line after changes: `source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: The more zshrc-like way of doing this is `npm set prefix ~/.npm; path+=$HOME/.npm/bin; path+=./node_modules/.bin`  (using path+= rather than appending the existing path to each line like in bash)

Comment: what about [fish](https://fishshell.com/)?

Answer (score 5):

This command will change the owner (chown) recursively (-R) for the current user in the specified directory

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: If you added an explanation to your answer, the answer would be greatly improved

Answer (score 3):

To all the warnings telling not to use `sudo` above, I'd add the following solution that worked pretty well for me while installing [n, node version manager](https://github.com/tj/n)

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules`

This was taken from here: https://poopcode.com/missing-write-access-to-usr-local-lib-node-modules/

PS: for my specific use-case I also needed to run this one afterwards

`sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin/`

Comment: It seems odd that the preferred way to fix this is to make a subpath of /usr not be owned by root. Does npm not have an equivalent of pip's `--user` flag?

Comment: Actually, it does have such a mechanism--something like `npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725639/npm-install-g-less-does-not-work-eacces-permission-denied/40905762#40905762

Answer (score 0):

Well, I used `--save-dev` and installed it not globally or using `-g`, the main problem occurs while you want it to write on default `node_modules` folder.

It solved my problem after 4 hours of checking multiple issues.

I even suggest you to use the `npm init` and make a `package.json` for a better dependency checking and then `run npm` install afterward. this video helps you for this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTsz09zRuTU

Answer (score 0):

Please **dont** use `sudo`.

*I don't know the context of your environment*, but I got the error on a server where Plesk was running.

Maybe the following command will help (via SSH) to check the permissions:

`plesk repair fs example.com`.

Manual: https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/administrator-guide/plesk-administration/plesk-repair-utility/plesk-repair-utility-file-system.74668/

In my case the `node_modules` folder was copied via FTP and therefore it had the wrong corrections. If necessary, you can remove this and install it via Plesk using the `Npm installation` button.

*Info: The button only appears if the document contains a `package.json` with information.*

Answer (score -5):

it is very simple
you can use

> sudo npm install -g kazam

or

> su -

then

> npm install -g kazam

explenation

```
su -
```

makes you as root ,who have permission to  read , write and delete in all users
[click here for the screen shot showing the error and the solution in the update of npm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7Fls.png)

> ```
> this is for ubuntu i don't know is it work for other os
> ```