# Fix error permission denied "/Users/name/Library/Application Support/Lens/node_modules/lenscloud-lens-extension" while open lens apps

Tags: kubernetes, npm

How to fix pop up error [permission denied](http:///Users/162408.suryadi/Library/Application%20Support/Lens/node_module/lenscloud-lens-extension)?

The log:

```
    50 silly saveTree +-- lens-survey@5.2.5-latest.20211001.2
    50 silly saveTree +-- lens-telemetry@5.2.5-latest.20211001.2
    50 silly saveTree `-- lenscloud-lens-extension@5.2.5-latest.20211001.2
    51 warn Lens No description
    52 warn Lens No repository field.
    53 warn Lens No license field.
    54 verbose stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/162408.suryadi/Library/Application Support/Lens/node_modules/lenscloud-lens-extension'
    55 verbose cwd /Users/162408.suryadi/Library/Application Support/Lens
    56 verbose Darwin 20.4.0
    57 verbose argv "/Applications/Lens.app/Contents/Frameworks/Lens Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Lens Helper" "/Applications/Lens.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "install" "--no-audit" "--only=prod" "--prefer-offline" "--no-package-lock"
    58 verbose node v14.16.0
    59 verbose npm  v6.14.13
    60 error code EACCES
    61 error syscall access
    62 error path /Users/162408.suryadi/Library/Application Support/Lens/node_modules/lenscloud-lens-extension
    63 error errno -13
    64 error Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/162408.suryadi/Library/Application Support/Lens/node_modules/lenscloud-lens-extension'
    64 error  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/162408.suryadi/Library/Application Support/Lens/node_modules/lenscloud-lens-extension'] {
    64 error   errno: -13,
    64 error   code: 'EACCES',


Could not load extensions: npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/162408.suryadi/Library/Application Support/Lens/node_modules/lenscloud-lens-extension
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/162408.suryadi/Library/Application Support/Lens/node_modules/untitled folder/package.json'
npm WARN Lens No description
npm WARN Lens No repository field.
npm WARN Lens No license field.

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /Users/162408.suryadi/Library/Application Support/Lens/node_modules/lenscloud-lens-extension
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/162408.suryadi/Library/Application Support/Lens/node_modules/lenscloud-lens-extension'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/162408.suryadi/Library/Application Support/Lens/node_modules/lenscloud-lens-extension'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/162408.suryadi/Library/Application Support/Lens/node_modules/lenscloud-lens-extension'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/162408.suryadi/.npm/_logs/2021-10-21T02_16_36_016Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your logs you can find the description of your problem:

> It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user.

And one more thing to check:

> If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running the command again as root/Administrator.

The error you got is because you cannot access the resource `/Users/162408.suryadi/Library/Application Support/Lens/node_modules/lenscloud-lens-extension` from the current user. If you want to fix it, you have to change the permissions for this resource or change its owner. It is also possible (since you are using Kubernetes) that you will have to make such a change in the image of the system you are using.

To change owner the resource run

```
sudo chown -R $USER /Users/162408.suryadi/Library/Application Support/Lens/node_modules/lenscloud-lens-extension
```

You can find also many similar problems. In most cases, the only difference will be the different path to the resource. The mode of operation and the solution to the problem remains the same:

- [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910876/error-eacces-permission-denied-access-usr-local-lib-node-modules)
- [npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52979927/npm-warn-checkpermissions-missing-write-access-to-usr-local-lib-node-modules)
- https://progressivecoder.com/how-to-easily-fix-missing-write-access-error-npm-install/
- https://flaviocopes.com/npm-fix-missing-write-access-error/